# Django ordering by the sum of two fields not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, pycharm

I am trying to order my users by answeredQuestion / questions

I have the following model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    questions = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    answeredQuestions = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

And I am trying the following:

```
users = User.objects.extra(
        select={'fieldsum': 'answeredQuestions / questions'},
        order_by=('-fieldsum',)
```

Yet, when changing out the ('-fieldsum') for just ('fieldsum'), it still produces the same result.
I have also tried the following:

```
users = User.objects.annotate(total=F('answeredQuestions') / F('questions')).order_by('total')
```

But even using this, I always get the same result, and the Users remain ordered wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to specify the `output_field` for the newly generated field because `F()` does not support it by default. You can do it by enclosing it in an `ExpressionWrapper()`. Try this.

```
users = User.objects.annotate(
    totalQs=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('answeredQuestions') / F('questions'), output_field=Integer())).order_by('totalQs')
```

Comment: I couldn't test this out until now. How do I get the Integer() as it's just underlined red. What do I have to import? Edit: Ok, I think I figured it out: I did the following: from integer import Integer, now I get the following Error after starting: TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'